# Problem using double colon expression in Java

Tags: java, lambda, method-reference

I have a method that calculates the number of posts made by a user like this:

```
public long nrPostUser(String user)
    {
        return this.posts.stream().filter(a-> a.getName().equals(user) ).count();
    }
```

as a training exercise i wanted to do the same thing but using a double colon operator instead of the lambda expression, I managed to do it by hardcoding the `user` parameter like so:

```
public long nrPostUser2(String user)
    {
        return  this.posts.stream().filter(FBPost::isUser).count();
    }

public boolean isUser()
    {
        return this.name.equals("1");
    }
```

My problem here is that I can't seem to make so that I can make use of a non-hardcoded version of this, from what I've seen it should be something like this:

```
public long nrPostUser3(String user)
    {
        Function<String,Boolean> func = FBPost::isUser2;
        return (int) this.posts.stream().filter(FBPost::isUser).count();
    }

public boolean isUser2(String user)
    {
        return this.name.equals(user);
    }
```

but that doesn't work.

Comment: To clarify, by hardcoding you mean using the function reference directly, as opposed to assigning it to a variable first and using the variable instead? I think it's totally fine and the feature was most likely designed to be used in this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
public long nrPostUser(String user) {
    return posts.stream()
            .map(FBPost::getName)
            .filter(user::equals)
            .count();
}
```

Because we're using `count` and ultimately don't care about the resulting stream before we call `count`, we can use `map` to get all the post's users before filtering on their equality with `user`.